# M Cloud activity query not populating DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to load last 6 months hard bounces into DE, using SQL Activity but it is not populating at all, with no errors. Here is my code.

[image]

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT s.SubscriberKey AS ID_EMAIL 
       , LOWER(s.EmailAddress)  AS EMAIL_ADDR  
       , b.BOUNCECATEGORY  
       , jb.JOBID 
       , jb.EMAILNAME  
 FROM _Subscribers s
 JOIN _Bounce b ON b.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
 JOIN _Job jb   ON jb.jobid = b.jobid
WHERE lower(b.BounceCategory) = 'hard bounce'
  AND b.EventDate >= DATEADD(m, -6, GetDate())
  AND (LOWER(jb.emailName) like '%client%'
      OR 
      LOWER(jb.emailName) like '%animal%'
      OR 
      LOWER(jb.emailName) like '%equine%'
      OR 
      LOWER(jb.emailName) like '%cat%'
      OR 
      LOWER(jb.emailName) like '%dog%'
      OR 
      LOWER(jb.emailName) like '%feline%'
      OR 
      LOWER(jb.emailName) like '%canine%'
      )
```

1. Data action = Update
2. run one time to test before I schedule.

Comment: Is this in a child bu? If so use ent._subscribers

Comment: @EazyE. You're right.  I have been working on child business unit so I needed to reference _Subscribers in the parent level as: ENT._Subscribers.